# Probability of a chance between two numbers

Tags: probability

I am just brushing up my maths. Could someone help me the process to find an answer to some situation as below:

In an exam there are possible score between 1 and 10 (both included, and no zeros). Student **A** gets 5 and **B** gets 8 out of 10. Suppose we randomly pick a student **C**, what is the probability that **C**'s score lies between **A** and **B**'s?

Comment: The posted solutions suppose some sort of uniformity...as though a student's score fell uniformly between $1$ and $10$.  That's not very likely, though you give no information about the distribution.  We could also guess at a normal distribution, with mean $\frac {5+8}2=6.5$ which would be more typical, though estimating a variance from two data points is still pretty much a guess. Still, as the mean is $6.5$ I'd just say the kids had an independent probability of $\frac {6.5}{10}$ of getting each  question right and compute from there.

Comment: Hi Lulu, thanks for the comment. Considering that the above given info is all what we have and no other assumptions are required to make, can we not accept the below answers? Just to reduce confusions, the scores are only integers (i.e. 1, 2, 3 upto 10).

Comment: I posted an alternate method.  As I say, uniformity is a terrible assumption here.  I have graded far more than my share of tests and I have never seen anything remotely uniform.  In this case, I think $20\%$ is far too low an estimate....the method I use gives nearly $50\%$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include the extreme scores, $C$'s score should be $5,6,7,8$ to match the request, so there are $4$ favorable cases out of $10$. The probability is therefore $4/10=40\%$. If you exclude the extreme cases, then C can only score $6$ or $7$ (resulting in a $20\%$ probability).

Comment: Thanks Vivo. yes I guess it should be 20% if we exclude A and B's scores.

Comment: You're welcome. This is what I wrote: if you exclude A and B's scores, it is $20\%$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the scores must be integers, there are exactly two scores that lie between a $5$ and an $8$ (noninclusive), and those are a $6$ or a $7$. That makes $2$ out of $10$, or a $1$ in $5$ chance.

If the score can be any real number between $1$ and $10$, then the possible score range is $3$ (from $8-5$), and this probability would thus be calculated as $3$ in $10$.

Comment: Hi Lanier... thanks for explanation.. but I guess it (the range) should be 2 (i.e. numbers 6 and 7, as we exclude 5 and 8). So this would turn out to be 20%, right?

Comment: I assume you're asking about the second part of my response. If the number didn't need to be an integer, student C could score as low as $5.000001$ and as high as $7.9999999$. So technically the range approaches $3$ if not using real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just to describe an alternate point of view:  uniform distribution of scores is extremely unlikely.  Normal distributions give a much better description of actual data like this, though we really don't have enough information to guess at a normal responsibly.  the path of least resistance is just to note that the mean score (using the two data points) is $6.5$ so we can pretend this was a Bernoulli distribution with win probability $.65$.  In that case the possible scores $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ have probabilities given by $$\{2.75855E-05,
0.000512302,
0.004281378,
0.021203015,
0.0689098,
0.153570411,
0.237668493,
0.252219625,
0.175652953,
0.072491695,
0.013462743\}$$

Thus the probability of getting a $6$ is about $.238$ and the probability of getting a $7$ is about $.252$ and these sum to about $.49$, or nearly half.  Of course we are still guessing at the distribution, but doing it this way seems a lot more realistic than guessing it is uniform.

To be sure, it's still a pretty crude method.  Assuming independence is bad, for example.  But I think the result looks pretty robust...$65\%$ is a typical target for a test mean, for example.

Comment: Nice and wonderful explanation. Thanks Lulu.